# RegExp range out of order with complex pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This is my pattern:

```
var pattern = "/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[\w\-]*\/)*([\w\-\.]*)/";
var matches = $("#search input").val().match(new RegExp(pattern));
```

When I use it, it gives me an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //(?:https?://)?(?:www.)?facebook.com/(?:(?:w)*#!/)?(?:pages/)?(?:[w-]*/)*([w-.]*)//: Range out of order in character class
```

From reading on another similar issues it came to my attention that I need to double escape some characters, but I don't know which out of all from my pattern.

Comment: how are you using this in your javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove unwanted double quotes from regex pattern:

```
 var pattern = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[\w\-]*\/)*([\w\-\.]*)/;
```

Comment: If you're willing to wait until StackOverflow allows me to do so.

Comment: Additionally, then you don't need the `new RegExp(pattern)` anymore; just use `pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

In a JavaScript String all backslashes should be replaced by double backslash

```
var pattern = "/(?:https?:\\/\\/)?(?:www\\.)?facebook\\.com\\/(?:(?:\\w)*#!\\/)?(?:pages\\/)?(?:[\\w\\-]*\\/)*([\\w\\-\\.]*)/";
```

Answer (score 0):

if its just about getting the `xyz` part from the url `http://www.facebook.com/xyz`

why not use split instead ?

something like this

```
var str = "http://www.facebook.com/xyz";
var res = str.split('/').pop();
console.log(res);
```

Comment: It's not about just getting the xyz part from the URL. :)